# VSCode syntax highlighting for custom shebang

Tags: visual-studio-code

At work we run python under a custom environment, and thus we use a non-standard shebang. I tested that VSCode recognizes python files *without* a .py extension if they have a shebang that's either `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `/usr/bin/python` or variants of these.

At work I use a shebang similar to this: `#!/some/directory/envroot "$ENVROOT/bin/python"` but vs code doesn't recognize this, so I have to manually set the language to python each time.

Is there a configuration somewhere that I can map a custom shebang to a language so I don't have to set it manually each time I open the file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I work on VSCode.

The shebang mapping is defined by `firstLine` in the extension grammar contributions:

```
    "languages": [{
        "id": "python",
        "extensions": [ ".py", ".rpy", ".pyw", ".cpy", ".gyp", ".gypi" ],
        "aliases": [ "Python", "py" ],
        "firstLine": "^#!/.*\\bpython[0-9.-]*\\b",
        "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
    }]
```

There is no setting to control this, but you could use [`file.associations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vMarch#_file-to-language-association) to map these files to python directly.

Your specific example also seems like a bug to me. We currently only use the first line pattern [if the entire line matches](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/base/common/mime.ts#L206), which seems odd. I've opened an issue to investigate this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21533

Comment: Thank you for the file associations tip! All these files are in the bin directory, so I should be able to use that to mark all of them as python.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Matt Bierner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42499652/45375):

The JSON settings Matt references are in `<languageId>/package.json` files in the following locations:

**On GitHub:**

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions
- E.g., for Python: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/python/package.json

**When installed**:

- In the `resources/app/extensions` subfolder of the VSCode installation folder; e.g.:

  - Windows (32-bit version):

    ```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions
    ```
  - macOS:

    ```
    /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions
    ```
- E.g, for Python:

  - Windows (32-bit version):

    ```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\python\package.json
    ```
  - macOS:

    ```
    /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/python/package.json
    ```

Answer (score 0):

And to complement [mklement0's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938267/8416256):
On Linux, see `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extension/`
E.g for Lua: `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/lua/package.json`